# New column in excisting array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array named $data containing this data:

```
Array
(
    [00:18] => 3.19
    [00:48] => 3.19
    [01:18] => 3.38
    [01:48] => 3.19
    [02:18] => 2.69
    [02:48] => 3.75
    [03:18] => 3.75
    [03:48] => 4.12
    [04:18] => 3.88

)
```

I want to add a new column in the end containing the date, the date is the same for all rows.

How would I do this?

Comment: did you want to add an element after this: [04:18] => 3.88 element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you want to add a date to each element in the array? to do that

```
$arr = your array;
$date = date("Y/m/d");
foreach($arr as &$element) {
   $element['date'] = $date;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
$data =array
(
    '00:18' => 3.19,
    '00:48' => 3.19,
    '01:18' => 3.38,
    '01:48' => 3.19,
    '02:18' => 2.69,
    '02:48' => 3.75,
    '03:18' => 3.75,
    '03:48' => 4.12,
    '04:18' => 3.88

);
$date = date("Y/m/d");
$data['date'] = $date;
print_r($data);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [00:18] => 3.19
    [00:48] => 3.19
    [01:18] => 3.38
    [01:48] => 3.19
    [02:18] => 2.69
    [02:48] => 3.75
    [03:18] => 3.75
    [03:48] => 4.12
    [04:18] => 3.88
    [date] => 2014/01/12
)
```

Comment: @TRS: Did you want this?